Sequelize no crea tablas pivot o relaciones entre tablas
Tengo un problema a la hora de crear llaves foranes y por ende crear tablas pivote o relaciones entre ellas.
Este es mi modelo aleatorio:
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../utils/connection');

const Student = sequelize.define('student', {
    campo1: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
});

module.exports = Student;

Este mi index.js donde alojo las relaciones de normalización de las tablas:
const Student = require("./Student");
const Ticher = require("./Ticher");

Student.belongsToMany(Ticher, { through: 'students_tichers' });
Ticher.belongsToMany(Student, { through: 'students_tichers' });

No importa que tipo de ralacion sea, simplemente sequelize no crea o las tablas o las llaves de relaciones, imposibilitando la creación de mis proyectos. Utilizo postgresSQL y no sé si el problema sea netamente del ORM o de postgres.
